# Accordion with nested sublevels

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested, accordion

My colleague did a single-level accordion for our internal web, which I'd like to develop into a multi-level accordion (I'd like 3 levels in the final version). I tried adding a sublevel to the accordion by making a new css-part ('questionv3') and expanding the if-statement in the js to inherit that as well.
However, the nested content is not properly displayed when I run the code. I sense that my approach with adding divs in divs is not working.

Any suggestions on how I can make this Work? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/discoking1986/pen/amaZYw

```
var dhtmlgoodies_slideSpeed = 50; // Higher value = faster
var dhtmlgoodies_timer = 5; // Lower value = faster

var objectIdToSlideDown = false;
var dhtmlgoodies_activeId = false;
var dhtmlgoodies_slideInProgress = false;
var dhtmlgoodies_slideInProgress = false;
var dhtmlgoodies_expandMultiple = true; // true if you want to be able to have multiple items expanded at the same time.

function showHideContent(e,inputId)
{
 if(dhtmlgoodies_slideInProgress)return;
 dhtmlgoodies_slideInProgress = true;
 if(!inputId)inputId = this.id;
 inputId = inputId + '';
 var numericId = inputId.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
 var answerDiv = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_a' + numericId);

 objectIdToSlideDown = false;

 if(!answerDiv.style.display || answerDiv.style.display=='none'){
  if(dhtmlgoodies_activeId &&  dhtmlgoodies_activeId!=numericId && !dhtmlgoodies_expandMultiple){
   objectIdToSlideDown = numericId;
   slideContent(dhtmlgoodies_activeId,(dhtmlgoodies_slideSpeed*-1));
  }else{

   answerDiv.style.display='block';
   answerDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';

   slideContent(numericId,dhtmlgoodies_slideSpeed);
  }
 }else{
  slideContent(numericId,(dhtmlgoodies_slideSpeed*-1));
  dhtmlgoodies_activeId = false;
 }
}
function slideContent(inputId,direction)
{

 var obj =document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_a' + inputId);
 var contentObj = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_ac' + inputId);
 height = obj.clientHeight;
 if(height==0)height = obj.offsetHeight;
 height = height + direction;
 rerunFunction = true;
 if(height>contentObj.offsetHeight){
  height = contentObj.offsetHeight;
  rerunFunction = false;
 }
 if(height<=1){
  height = 1;
  rerunFunction = false;
 }

 obj.style.height = height + 'px';
 var topPos = height - contentObj.offsetHeight;
 if(topPos>0)topPos=0;
 contentObj.style.top = topPos + 'px';
 if(rerunFunction){
  setTimeout('slideContent(' + inputId + ',' + direction + ')',dhtmlgoodies_timer);
 }else{
  if(height<=1){
   obj.style.display='none';
   if(objectIdToSlideDown && objectIdToSlideDown!=inputId){
    document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_a' + objectIdToSlideDown).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_a' + objectIdToSlideDown).style.visibility='visible';
    slideContent(objectIdToSlideDown,dhtmlgoodies_slideSpeed);
   }else{
    dhtmlgoodies_slideInProgress = false;
   }
  }else{
   dhtmlgoodies_activeId = inputId;
   dhtmlgoodies_slideInProgress = false;
  }
 }
}



function initShowHideDivs()
{
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
 var divCounter = 1;
 for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
  if(divs[no].className=='questionV2'|| divs[no].className=='questionV3'){
   divs[no].onclick = showHideContent;
   divs[no].id = 'dhtmlgoodies_q'+divCounter;
   var answer = divs[no].nextSibling;
   while(answer && answer.tagName!='DIV'){
    answer = answer.nextSibling;
   }
   answer.id = 'dhtmlgoodies_a'+divCounter;
   contentDiv = answer.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];
   contentDiv.style.top = 0 - contentDiv.offsetHeight + 'px';
   contentDiv.className='answer_content';
   contentDiv.id = 'dhtmlgoodies_ac' + divCounter;
   answer.style.display='none';
   answer.style.height='1px';
   divCounter++;
  }
 }
}
window.onload = initShowHideDivs;

@charset "utf-8";
   .questionV2{ /* Styling question */
    /* Start layout CSS */
    width:432px;
    border:1px solid #46743c;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #77966c;
    position:relative;
    /* End layout CSS */
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.questionV3{    /* Styling question */
    /* Start layout CSS */
    width:380px;
    border:1px solid #46743c;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #6dbc4a;
    position:relative;
    /* End layout CSS */
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .answer{    /* Parent box of slide down content */
    /* Start layout CSS */
    margin:0px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:464px;
    /* End layout CSS */
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    border-top: none;
    }
    .answer_content{    /* Content that is slided down */
    /* Start layout CSS */
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    width:464px;
    /* End layout CSS */
    }

<div class="questionV2">Level 1</div>
<div class="answer">
<div>
  <p>Some text goes here</p>
<div class="questionV3">Sub-level 1</div>
<div class="answer">
<div>
<p>Some text goes here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="questionV2">Level 2</div>
<div class="answer">
<div>
  <p>Some text goes here</p>
<div class="questionV3">Sub-level 2</div>
<div class="answer">
<div>
<p>Some text goes here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't fit the parameters of your question, but have you seen [this](https://codepen.io/rbobrowski/pen/likvA) codepen?

Comment: @vladdobra yes. I have looked up several working solutions, but so far I haven't succeeded implementing any of them. I may be doing it wrong though. We are running on an old Sharepoint 2007 - system, and I've tried adding the Jquery library to make some of these solutions usable via the Content Editor Webpart, but nothing is rendered as it supposed to. If you have any suggestions how I could approach it I'd be more than happy.

Comment: Just to be clear: that one you posted is perfect according to my wishes - I just can't figure how to implement it in SP2007

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to work sharepoint. However, if you are able to in your system, you [could try](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-multi-level-accordion-menu/) to use a css only approach. Again, never used a system like that, so I have no idea what the bounds are, and whether you can even use css3.